# Why can't I reference UI elements in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have been trying to reference a UI element/elements from a fragment in Android Studio but it won't detect the id of the item I'm trying to reference, what's wrong with my code? the title_et is an EditText object but it's not detected so it just turns into a red error cause it can't find it.

```
private fun insertDataToDb() {

    val mTitle = title_et.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.title_et).text.toString()

}
```

This is the full class/code

```
package com.celestestudios.eltodolistero.fragments.add

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.celestestudios.eltodolistero.R


class AddFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)

        // Set Menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_fragment_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.menu_add){
            insertDataToDb()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun insertDataToDb() {

        val mTitle = title_et.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.title_et).text.toString()

    }

}
```

Comment: Replace `title_et.findViewById` with `view.findViewById`.

Comment: This actually might work, I just have to add a ? after view, i'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method initializeViews and pass view as parameter and initialize views

```
package com.celestestudios.eltodolistero.fragments.add

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.celestestudios.eltodolistero.R


class AddFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)
         initializeViews(view)
        // Set Menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_fragment_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.menu_add){
            insertDataToDb()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    private fun initializeViews(view){
     val mTitle = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.title_et).text.toString()
}

    private fun insertDataToDb() {

        

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get this solution, I cannot call/use mTitle from the function insertDataToDb()

Comment: Maybe If I add "view : View" as a parameter I can use it inside of insertDataToDb() except I have to add view to it like this insertDataToDb(view)

Edit: that did not work buuuut I managed to use this way to get it to stop giving out an error, I still have to try it though..


                                                                                                                                        val mTitle = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.title_et)?.text.toString()